# Convert Pandas dataframe to list of list with index, data, and columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a `Pandas` dataframe that I'd like to convert to a list of list where each sublist is a row in the dataframe. How would I also include the index values so that I can later output it to PDF table with `ReportLab`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['Index 1', 'Index 2'],
                  data=[[1,2],[3,4]],
                  columns=['Column 1', 'Column 2'])

list = [df.columns[:,].values.astype(str).tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
print list
```

output:

```
[['Column 1', 'Column 2'], [1L, 2L], [3L, 4L]]
```

desired output:

```
[['Column 1', 'Column 2'], ['Index 1', 1L, 2L], ['Index 2', 3L, 4L]]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
In [29]:
[df.columns.tolist()] + df.reset_index().values.tolist()
Out[29]:
[['Column 1', 'Column 2'], ['Index 1', 1L, 2L], ['Index 2', 3L, 4L]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly also include the index name (df.index.name) so that all rows have the same number of columns.

```
[[df.index.name] + df.columns.tolist()] + df.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

add a list comprehension in this line:

```
list = [df.columns[:,].values.astype(str).tolist()] + [[index] + vals for index,value in zip(df.index.tolist(),df.values.tolist())]
```

also, because you have your columns in your first item as `item[colindex] = column at colindex`,  I would maybe change: `['Index 1',x1,y1]` to `[x1,y1,'Index 1']`? I dont know if the position of `Index` item matters but this seems to make more sense so that the columns line up? Although I dont know how you are using your data so maybe not :)

EDITTED: `df.index.tolist()` is better than `df.index.values.tolist()` and i think it returns just items so you need to initialize `[index]` as a list instead of just `index`

Comment: This works but you are physically typing in Index and then appending the number, what if my indexes were name random stuff?

Comment: i had not realized you were using your index values! totally my bad, editted to reflect that. instead of enumerating, it zips the values of `df.index.values` and `df.values`